# RN: How to use uri for local image file source

Tags: react-native

Here is an example of `Image` in [RN document](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, View, Image } from 'react-native';

export default class DisplayAnImage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Image
          source={require('/react-native/img/favicon.png')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

For local image file, it uses `source = {require('path-to-image-file')}`. My render code is as below:

```
     <View>
        <Image
          style={{width:150, height:100,borderRadius:13,margin:3, resizeMode:'cover'}}
          source={require("./image1.jpg")}  //<<tested working for image file resides in the same subdir of component
         />
      </View>
```

I am trying to convert the format to `uri: ""` for `source`.  here is a list of strings tried and not work for a local file `image1.jpg` which resides in the same subdir of the component:

```
source={{uri: "./image1.jpg"}}
source={{uri: "/image1.jpg"}}
source={{uri: "image1.jpg"}}
source={{uri: "file:///image1.jpg"}}
source={{uri: "file: //image1.jpg"}}
source={{uri: "file:/image1.jpg"}}
source={{uri: "file: image1.jpg"}} //<<== syntax error
```

What is the right format for `uri` source?

Comment: Adding why would help others for answering this question.

Comment: when you are working with `uri`,RN does not include height and width, just add ` style={{width: 50, height: 50}}` and you are good to use `source={{uri: '/react-native/img/favicon.png'}}`

Comment: `source={require("./image1.jpg")}` for a image file resided in the same subdir works fine. Converting to `uri`,  none of the `{uri: "image1.jpg"}`, `{uri: "/image1.jpg"}` and `{uri: "./image1.jpg"}` works. Those are all valid uri strings. What else need to do to make uri string working here?